# Unable to get the date from tempusdominus bootstrap4 plugin to Django form

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

Here is my html code.

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <label> Approved Date:</label>
    <div class="input-group date" id="{{ form.ApprovedDate.id_for_label }}"
         data-target-input="nearest">
        <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" id="{{ form.ApprovedDate.id_for_label }}" name="{{ form.ApprovedDate.id_for_label }}"
               data-target="#{{ form.ApprovedDate.id_for_label }}"/>
        <div class="input-group-append"
             data-target="#{{ form.ApprovedDate.id_for_label }}"
             data-toggle="datetimepicker">
            <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is the Script Jquery

```
    <script>
        $(function () {

            $('#{{ form.ApprovedDate.id_for_label }}').datetimepicker({
                format: 'DD-MM-YYYY'
            });
        })
    </script>
```

My problem is that this field is not being passed to my django form which is of this code.

```
class ProjectForm(forms.ModelForm): #views.py
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = '__all__'

    def save(self, commit=True):
        instance = super().save(commit=False)
        instance.created_on = timezone.now()  # Import timezone if not already imported
        instance.createdBy = 0
        if commit:
            instance.save()
        return instance

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in iter(self.fields):
            self.fields[field].widget.attrs.update({
                'class': 'form-control'
            })
```

I simply want to read value of this field so the same can be saved to db. by this code in views.py

```
def create_project(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProjectForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()  # Save to the database with the modified fields
            return redirect('projects:project_list')  # Redirect to the list view
    else:
        form = ProjectForm()
    return render(request, 'create_project.html', {'form': form})
```

I have tried many solutions like importing tempusdominus package but I want it to be simple, just get the value in the date format so the same can be sent to the db.

PS: I am new to Django and from Code Java (JSP (read ugly) ) coding background and has started learning Django.

Answer (score 1):

It was very simple with the help of this link.
https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2019/01/03/how-to-use-date-picker-with-django.html#tempus-dominus-bootstrap-4

we need to

```html
from django import forms

class DateForm(forms.Form):
    date = forms.DateTimeField(
        input_formats=['%d/%m/%Y %H:%M'],
        widget=forms.DateTimeInput(attrs={
            'class': 'form-control datetimepicker-input',
            'data-target': '#datetimepicker1'
        })
    )
```